# How do I view the auto layout constraint for a single UIElement

Tags: xcode, storyboard, autolayout

Using auto layouts on a view with lots of UIElements can get really messy. To make things worse, I don't know how to reorder or arrange them they way I want it to. I spend a lot of time scanning all the constraints until I find the one I need to fix.

Is there a view to only view the layout constraint for the UIElement that is selected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the UI element and select size inspector. There it enlists constraints of that UI element only. I think that is neat already.

Comment: You mean the Size inspector. Also, from there you can double-click a constraint and that selects it in the document outline (and shows its details in the Size inspector that you're already looking at).